# What does the "in" keyword do in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am having trouble understanding the full scope of the 'in' keyword in haskell. It was my understanding that you could use it to pass arguments to a function. However, I am having trouble understanding how the applies to a function similar to that shown below:

```
foo xs a =
   case xs of
      [] -> (a,[])
      y:ys ->
         let (n,ns)=foo ys a in
         if y>0 then (1+n,y:ns)
         else (n,ns)
```

How does 'in' apply to the equation if it is supplying parameters that foo does not take?

Comment: (1) Nitpicking: `in` is not a standalone keyword; it is always accompanied by `let`: `let {- definitions -} in {- expression that uses the definitions -}`. (2) In your case, the let-expression defines `n` and `ns`, in terms of `foo`, `ys` and `a`.

Comment: @duplode That's not nitpicking, that's the answer. You should post it as such.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I can't write a full answer in a satisfactory way right now. I will do it later if other answers do not cover it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`in` goes along with `let` to name one or more local expressions in a pure function.

So, to use a simpler example,

```
foo = 
  let greeting = "hello" in 
    print (greeting ++ " world")
```

would print "hello world".

But you could also use lots of `let`s:

```
foo = 
  let greeting = "hello"
      greetee  = "world" in
    print (greeting ++ " " ++ greetee)
```

And you just need one `in` before you use the names you just defined.

And these names definitely don't *have* to be used as parameters to a function -- they can be just about anything, even functions themselves!

```
foo = 
  let f = print in
    f "hello world"
```

In your example, the `let` expression is defining two names, `n` and `ns`, which are used in the body of the function.